# Why did flutter stop being recognized on Windows and how to fix it?

Tags: windows, flutter, path, console

For the last 4 weeks I have been learning flutter development on Windows until suddenly my Visual Studio notified me that it cannot find flutter package on my PC.

I have checked the console and surprisingly command "flutter" is no longer recognized, not only in cmd.exe, but even in flutter_console.bat. Path variable is still fine and location of flutter hasn't changed.

[flutter_console.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WaZn.png)

Any ideas what could happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*From the Start search bar, enter ‘env’ and select Edit environment variables for your account.
Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path:
    If the entry exists, append the full path to flutter\bin using ; as a separator from existing values.
    If the entry doesn’t exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full path to flutter\bin as its value.
```

Note that you have to close and reopen any existing console windows for these changes to take effect*
then run `flutter doctor`  and `flutter upgrade`